# Calling native code from an AOT-compiled Java application using CNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ld, gcj, libgcj

[*GNU Compiler for Java*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) provides two methods to invoke native code from a Java application.

1. First, there's a [*JNI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) specification authored by *Sun Microsystems*, and GCJ adheres to this specification.
2. Second, there's *CNI*, the [Compiled Native Interface](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.5.0/gcj/About-CNI.html) implemented by GCJ alone, which is barely documented but allows native methods to be implemented in C++, providing a higher-level API to interact between native code and JVM.

Now, since GCJ also allows ahead-of-time compilation, this gives us the following opportunities to call native code from Java code:

1. Run the regular JVM with `gij`, load your main-class which will load the native library using [`System.loadLibrary()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)), and invoke the native method. This is the conventional way we are used to when dealing with Sun/Oracle JVMs.
2. Same as above, but AOT-compile your bytecode into native code using `gcj`, and dynamically link the resulting executable against the external native library using the `-l` switch. The call to `System.loadLibrary()` may be preserved for compatibility, but is actually unnecessary, since the library will already be loaded by the dynamic interpreter long before the JVM is created. There're actually three sub-options:

   - Have the library loaded by the JVM, via `System.loadLibrary()`, quite similarly to [`dlopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).
   - Have the library being linked against by `ld`, via `gcj -l`. This is more convenient than the `loadLibrary()` approach, since you can pass the `-rpath` switch to the linker and avoid the need to manually set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running the executable.
   - None of the above, but have the library preloaded via `LD_PRELOAD`.
3. Statically link the AOT-compiled Java object with the object produced from the native code portion. This completely saves us from the need to call `System.loadLibrary()` (since there's no library), making the code of of the native method immediately available in the resulting executable.

Since we have two protocols to access native code (JNI and CNI), this doubles the amount of options available (from **3** to **6**).

While the approach of CNI with static linking works like a charm, I want to also explore how dynamic linking works together with CNI and AOT compilation, and this fails at link time.

Consider I have a simple main class:

```java
public final class Main {
        static {
                System.loadLibrary("foo");
        }

        private Main() {
                assert false;
        }

        public static native void foo();

        public static void main(final String args[]) {
                foo();
        }
}
```

The `Main.h` CNI header produced from it looks like this:

```cpp
#ifndef __Main__
#define __Main__

#pragma interface

#include <java/lang/Object.h>
#include <gcj/array.h>

extern "Java"
{
    class Main;
}

class Main : public ::java::lang::Object
{

  Main();
public:
  static void foo();
  static void main(JArray< ::java::lang::String * > *);
public: // actually package-private
  static jboolean $assertionsDisabled;
public:
  static ::java::lang::Class class$;
};

#endif // __Main__
```

... and here's the pretty standard default implementation of the shared library:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <gcj/cni.h>

#include "Main.h"

void Main::foo() {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

When linking the object produced from a Java main class with an external library:

```bash
gcj -pie -fPIE -save-temps --main=Main -o cni-dynamic-native -L/opt/gcc64/6.5/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/opt/gcc64/6.5/lib64 -L. -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' -lstdc++ -lgcj -lfoo Main.class
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Main.o: in function `void Main::main(JArray<java::lang::String*>*)':
Main.java:13: undefined reference to `hidden alias for void Main::foo()'
/usr/bin/ld: Main.o:(.data.rel+0xc0): undefined reference to `hidden alias for void Main::foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Indeed, if I examine the `Main.o` object with `nm`, there's the undefined symbol:

```
                 U hidden alias for void Main::foo()
```

The symbol is present in the shared library (`libfoo.so`) I'm linking against. It's *global* (`T`) in the object file but *static* (`t`) in the shared library.

```
0000000000001180 t hidden alias for void Main::foo()
```

The same problem is described in [this bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4266), but, unfortunately, there's no solution.
As I said, everything works perfectly when linking two objects statically using CNI or dynamically using JNI ([sample code](https://github.com/unix-junkie/gcj-cni-example)).

So, how do I load a native library into an AOT-compiled executable using the CNI interface? Was CNI ever intended for dynamic linking?

Comment: If you won't want to have someone answer your question "Anyone still remembers how to use GCJ?" (which is "yes") you should ask one that is more thoughtful.  Also consider reading "Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @possum That was just a rhetorical question, and I was assuming the actual question was already perfectly clear by the moment one read the post till the end. Reworded.

Comment: I looked into this somewhat and found that the "hidden alias" symbol type (mangled `_ZGA`) was only ever used as a java-specific thing built-in to g++ itself, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/cp/decl2.c;h=848f11cbbc60fc4d739c9d89536d159d8afd5674;hb=e31ae982c446804d1b259554203401392b078364#l4085). I can't see any interface to disable it besides rebuilding gcc 6.5 with `HAVE_GAS_HIDDEN` undefined. Doing that and also inspecting the `libjava` build artifacts might provide some clues on CNI dynamic linking.